# How to add a new pdf file when exporting to PDF using Kendo UI?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, pdf, kendo-ui

In .blade.php, the `img` works but `iframe` embeded and object don't:

```html
<img style="width: 100px" src="{{$inspection->profile_photo_url}}" alt="">

<iframe src="{{$inspection->pdf_report_url}}" width="100%" height="100%">
</iframe>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    kendo.drawing.drawDOM($('.content'))
        .then(function(group) {
            // render the result as a PDF file
            return kendo.drawing.exportPDF(group, {
                paperSize: 'auto',
                margin: { left: '1cm', top: '1cm', right: '1cm', bottom: '1cm' }
            });
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            kendo.saveAs({
                dataURI: data,
                filename: "<?php echo 'inspections-report'.$inspection->id.'.pdf'; ?>"
            });
            window.close();
        });
});
// window.print();
```

I have a blade.php page that generates (and automatically downloads) a pdf report using Kendo UI. In this report I need to include another pdf file. Does anyone know if it's possible to do that? I can add an image, but I tried adding a pdf file from url using iframe but that doesn't work.

[I wrote here details about my problem, can anyone help me?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QodRT.png)

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.